# Need to quit a process from inside Qt GUI, just as it is started

Tags: qt, qprocess, qtembedded

I am trying to run C++ executables placed inside SBC6845 [inside /ftest as shown ]. Now these executables are running with

```
while(1){
// around 250-300 lines of code here
}
```

infinite loop. Now when I run only the codes from terminal, I can kill them whenever I want to. But I am unable to kill them while running from inside the gui. I execute these codes with Qprocess like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
ui->setupUi(this);

connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(pressed()), SLOT(vcm_test()));
connect(ui->pushButton_2, SIGNAL(pressed()), SLOT(offloader_test()));
connect(ui->pushButton_3, SIGNAL(pressed()), SLOT(quit_vcm()));
connect(ui->pushButton_4, SIGNAL(pressed()), SLOT(quit_offloader()));}
void MainWindow::vcm_test(){
   QProcess::execute("/ftest/vcm_test_2 \r\n");
}
void MainWindow::offloader_test(){
    QProcess::execute("/ftest/off_test_2 \r\n");
}  
void MainWindow::quit_vcm(){
    QProcess::execute("\x001a \r\n");
} 
void MainWindow::quit_offloader(){
    QProcess::execute("\x001a \r\n");   
}
```

Now the problem is when the **pushbutton** or **pushbutton_2** i.e. `vcm_test()` or `offloader_test()` is invoked the gui becomes unresponsive. Since the gui keeps waiting for the code in /ftest to finish quit option does not work and I have to quit it from the terminal again. Also quitting from terminal closes both the code and the gui.

I have tried searching solutions and used threads too. But I get segmentation error while starting a thread from pushbutton.

I need to be able to quit the process while it is being executed (modification of this code or any new idea is very much appreciated). I am a newbie so please ignore my poor coding skills. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QProcess::execute(..)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#execute) waits for the process to finish, that is why your GUI is freezing. Use [QProcess::start(..)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start) instead. To quit the process use the [QProcess::close()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#close) function

Try this:

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
myProcess->start("/ftest/vcm_test_2");
```

And when you want to close the process:

```
myProcess->close();
```

You can also connect your pushbutton's clicked signal to the process' kill slot:

```
connect(ui->pushButton_3, SIGNAL(clicked()), myProcess, SLOT(kill());
```

Comment: I am getting segmentation fault when I put myProcess->start(); inside vcm_test() and invoke it by calling through pushbutton. Any suggestions?

Comment: @truestorybro Can you start any process or does it always result in segmentation fault? Did you initialize your process? (myProcess = new QProcess(this))?

Comment: Actually I did a mistake in the initialization process.It is working fine, although the output from the executables are not getting displayed in the terminal now. I can know that it is working from the fact that I can see the offloader physically move when I press the Pushbutton. Thanks.

Comment: @truestorybro If you want to print the output you can use the [readyRead](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal of the QProcess and connect it to a slot, where you print the contents out. You can also start the process in its own window using the [startDetached(..)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#startDetached-3) function.

Comment: Ok, what function do I need if I want to display the same output, (which gets displayed into normal terminal through /dev/ttyUSB0) into QTextEdit (touchscreen connected through /dev/tty0 ) of the executables.

Comment: When you connect QProcess' readyRead() signal to one of your slots, you can read the contents by using your process' [readAll()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readAll) function. Then you can append the read data to your QTextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a QProcess object and call start() on it. That way the code doesn't get blocked when you execute the process untill it is finished.

```
QProcess* myprocess=new QProcess();
myprocess->start("/ftest/vcm_test_2");
```

You can if you want get a signal from myprocess to know if the process is finished. Which is in your case not usefull.
You can also close the process by invoking

```
myprocess->close();
```

Hope that helpes.